# Disconnect between UI and backend data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm having trouble with a PUT request updating properly.  I have a table titled 'issues' with the following columns:

```
title: title of issue,
description: description of issue,
zipcode: zipcode of issue,
upvotes: number of upvotes an issue receives // defaults to 0
```

For each issue created, a card is displayed that presents the information above.  I want to be able to click on a button that increases the upvote column by +1 on every click.  Right now, there is a disconnect between the click and the actual data.  The UI's number is always 1 ahead of the backend.  If the UI displays 17, for example, the backend reads 16, and so on.  I've tried a bunch of different combinations thus far to no avail.

I'm using React and Node/Express for this project.

A thought:

I didn't know if it was related to the my component hierarchy or not, but include both components just in case.

Below is the code my for the card displaying the individual 'issues':

```
/** @jsx jsx */

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Button, Card } from 'semantic-ui-react'

function IssueCard({ issue }) {
  const [currentIssue, setCurrentIssue] =  useState(issue);
  const [editedIssue, setEditedIssue] = useState(currentIssue);

  // Local storage management
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');

  // Issue ID to be used as dynamic param
  const id = issue.id;

  console.log("EDITED ISSUE", editedIssue);

  // Once chevron is clicked, the # of upvotes increases by 1
  function upvoteIssue() {
    // Change state to +1 for upvote
    setEditedIssue({ ...editedIssue, upvotes: editedIssue.upvotes + 1 });

    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:3000/issues/${id}`, editedIssue, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        // When I log the response, the first click doesn't increase upvote, but the second click does
        console.log("RESPONSE", response.data)
        setCurrentIssue(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header>{ issue.title }</Card.Header>
          <Card.Meta>{ issue.zipcode }</Card.Meta>
          <Card.Description>
            { issue.description }
          </Card.Description>
        </Card.Content>
        <div
         css={{
           marginLeft: '12px',
           marginBottom: '10px'
         }}
        >
          <Button
            size='huge'
            icon='heart'
            label={{ as: 'p', basic: true, content: editedIssue.upvotes }}
            labelPosition='right'
            onClick={upvoteIssue}
          />
        </div>
      </Card>
    </>
  )
};

export default IssueCard;
```

Below is the code for the parent component, which is just a profile page that lists the issues if there are any:

```
/** @jsx jsx */

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/core';
import { useTheme } from 'emotion-theming';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Banner from './Banner';
import { Button, Card, Icon, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import IssueCard from './IssueCard';
import profile_placeholder from '../images/profile_placeholder.png';

function Profile(props) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("");
    const [issues, setIssues] = useState([]);
    const [isEditingUser, setIsEditingUser] = useState(false);
    const [isEditingIssue, setIsEditingIssue] = useState(false);
    const [issueToUpdate, setIssueToUpdate] = useState({})
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    let id = window.localStorage.getItem('id')

    // Importing theme colors
    const theme = useTheme();

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchUser();
      fetchIssues();
    }, [])

    // Fetches user data to populate profile card with proper information
    function fetchUser() {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: token
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          setCurrentUser(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    };

    // Fetches the issues created by the logged user
    function fetchIssues() {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}/issues`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: token
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          setIssues(response.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    };

    return (
      <>
        <Banner />
        <div
          css={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginBottom: '50px'
          }}
        >
          <div
            css={{
              display: 'flex',
              marginTop: '50px'
            }}
          >
            <Card>
              <Image src={profile_placeholder} wrapped ui={false} />
              <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>{ currentUser.username }</Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>{ currentUser.email }</Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description>
                  { currentUser.biography }
                </Card.Description>
              </Card.Content>
              <Card.Content extra>
                <a>
                  <Icon name='user' />
                    Posted Issues: {currentUser.posted_issues}
                </a>
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          </div>

          <div
            css={{
              display: 'flex',
              marginTop: '20px'
            }}
          >
            <Link to="/addIssue">
              <Button 
                icon 
                labelPosition="left"
                color="facebook"
                size="huge"
              >
                <Icon name="add" />
                Add Issue
              </Button>
            </Link>

            <Button 
              icon 
              labelPosition="left"
              color="facebook"
              size="huge"
              >
              <Icon name="redo" />
              Edit Profile
            </Button>
          </div>

          <div
            css={{
              marginTop: '20px',
              backgroundColor: theme.colors.turquoise,
              width: '50%'
            }}
          >
            <h3
              css={{
                margin: '0px 10px',
                color: theme.colors.white
              }}
            >Issues created by { currentUser.username }:</h3>
          </div>
          {issues.map(issue => <IssueCard issue={issue} key={issue.id} /> )}
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

  export default Profile;
```